# Android: Is it possible to attach an existing DialogFragment to a new activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have an activity in my android app, which has many fragments (say A,B,C). I have a custom dialog fragment that I show by calling this code from one of the fragments (say A).

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
EditNameDialog editNameDialog = EditNameDialog.newInstance("Some Title");
editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
```

The color, text etc in the dialog fragment depend on some parameters. Now this fragment is shown as long as I am in one of the fragments A,B,C because the DialogFragment is attached to the same activity the fragments A,B,C are attached to.

Now at some point I migrate to another activity, which causes the dialog to appear. I want that the dialog shows as if it was attached to that activity and is in the same state as it was earlier. Now one way that I can think of doing this is to somehow use a fragment attached to the first activity instead of this second activity, but that will cause a lot of things to change. I wanted to know if their is a way of doing this with activities. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

> I want that the dialog shows as if it was attached to that activity and is in the same state as it was earlier. Now one way that I can think of doing this is to somehow use a fragment attached to the first activity instead of this second activity, but that will cause a lot of things to change.

So just save the state in i.e. DB, SharedPreferences etc. No trickery needed.